# Flying Saucer exception Font not recognized

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I am running into this exception using flying-saucer version 9.0.1

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font 'Courier-BoldOblique' with 'Cp1252' is not recognized.
         at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:451)
         at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:40)
         at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:113)
         at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:98)
```

I am a little lost as this is being thrown from flying saucer ITextfontResolver, seems I dont have much control over it.

Comment: Any ideas out there on how to troubleshoot.  This issue is popping up every few days and requires jboss recycle.  Then it will run fine on same set of data.

Comment: So, looks like issue coming when newing up :  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

Comment: So, looks like issue coming when newing up :  ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();     Deep into the renderer it is initializing the font map, but sometimes failes to create the type: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.  Frustrating because it runs fine for days/weeks then starts having issues.